# Utilising old CB Base Antena to 5g Antena

Tags: antenna, citizens-band

Is it possible to utilize an old CB Base Antenna (10 meters tall) as 5g Antenna to plug into the back of a 5g router that is currently only registering 4G? I have one on top of a single story unit that used to be a taxi booking office. I am surrounded by taller buildings hindering the 5g connection. TIA.

Answer (score 4):

A CB antenna will be designed for a frequency range around 27 MHz, much lower and also narrower than the bands used by 5G (multiple from [700 MHz to 6 GHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5G_NR_frequency_bands)). It *might* work better than nothing, but to get good results you need a proper antenna.

In principle, what you could do is reuse the *feed line* (coaxial cable) you already have installed, but remove the antenna and replace it with one suitable for your router. (The antenna that it came with, if any, would be perfect, except that it is probably not weather-proof.) It might be that the cable is not of a suitable quality to carry 6 GHz signals, though (either as originally manufactured, or due to damage from age or poor installation).

The best option would be to replace the feed line and antenna with ones known to be fit for this purpose — use just the roof mounting and the holes in the wall (or whatever) from the old antenna.